# Broken link to area51 page

Tags: bug, area-51, beta-sites, broken-link, 404-not-found

The sidebar on the right at https://rus.stackexchange.com/ links to an Area51 page at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/rus.stackexchange.com.

Regrettably, that page returns an Error 404.

Comment: Context: not knowing Russian, I was looking for a place with an English language explanation of what the site is about (purely for curiosity).

Comment: gerrit, https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://rus.stackexchange.com/&usg=ALkJrhhrrfemxTMbzj0a8xU7Ymzw6BJ4lQ